# focus on input trigger twice instead of only one trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am creating jquery plugin. I stuck on when i focus on input box then it triggered twice.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#searchText').typefast();
   $('#searchText1').typefast();
})
$.fn.typefast=function(){
   $('input').focus(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText1">
```

`

Comment: change it to $(this).focus(function()

Comment: Thanks all, I got the reason why it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's running twice because you are explicitly calling `typefast()` twice in your `document.ready` function. Even though your selectors were both missing the `#` in them, `typefast()` still gets called on the empty jQuery wrappers. And, since `typefast()` doesn't actually do anything with the contents of the wrapped set it gets called on, it goes ahead and processes on all `input` elements. So, the end result is that all `input` elements get `typefast` registered into their `focus` event twice.

If (and this is a big **if**) you were going to use a plug-in for this, you should just call it once because the plug-in finds all `input` elements and sets their event handler. Also, plug-ins have a certain pattern that is recommended to be followed to ensure that the `$` will, in fact, point to the jQuery object and to ensure that method chaining will work. That would look like this:

```js
$(function(){
   // You would want this to be a jQuery utility method (not a wrapped set method)
   // so you would set it up directly on jQuery, not jQuery.fn. This way, you can
   // just call it whenever you want without a wrapped set.
   $.typefast();
});

// By wrapping the plugin in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression
// that passes itself the jQuery object, we guarantee the $ will work
(function($){
  $.typefast = function(){
    $('input').focus(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });   
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText1">
```

But, there is no need for a jQuery plug-in here. This is not what plug-ins are for and you are not even **[writing it](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)** according to best practices. This is not the way to set up event handlers. All you need to do is set up an event handler for the `focus` event of the textboxes:

```js
// Just passing a function directly to the jQuery object is the same
// thing as explicitly setting a callback for document.ready
$(function(){
  // This is the function that will be called when any input gets the focus
  function typeFast(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  }
  
  // Set all input elements to call typeFast when they receive the focus
  $('input').on("focus", typeFast);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText1">
```

Comment: i dont want to add  on focus property on custom js file from where i want to call typefast instead i want my plugin function(typesfast) to catch which input is focused.

Comment: @Andrew Again, this is not what plug-ins are for. Plug-ins provide new functionality that doesn't already exist or encapsulate large code blocks into simply APIs. What you are asking for is already accomplished by my code.